# Loop command in R - unable to loop a command with a changing value inside the name of the variable

Tags: r, loops

I used to work on stata and i use this function when i wish to changes to a series of variable.

*Original sample data*

```r
df <- data.frame(Info_1i=c(1, 3, 3, 4, 5),
                 Info_1m=c(7, 3, NA, 4, 5),
                 Info_2i=c(3, 3, 6, 6, 8),
                 Info_2m=c(1, 1, 2, NA, 9),
                 Info_3i=c(1, 4, 5, 5, 5),
                 Info_3m=c(NA, 4, 5, 5, 5))
```

and what i wish to achieve is to be:

```r
df <- data.frame(Info_1i=c(1, 3, NA, 4, 5),
                 Info_1m=c(7, 3, NA, 4, 5),
                 Info_2i=c(3, 3, 6, NA, 8),
                 Info_2m=c(1, 1, 2, NA, 9),
                 Info_3i=c(NA, 4, 5, 5, 5),
                 Info_3m=c(NA, 4, 5, 5, 5))
```

In essence, the questions are paired, and if one question is answered as N/A, the paired question should be considered as NA as well. There are total of 50 over questions and I would hope to use a loop to clean it

In Stata, I would have used the following code.

*Sample code*

```
    forval x=1(1)(12) {
      Info_`x'i = 99 if Info_`x'm == 99
      Info_`x'm = 99 if Info_`x'i == 99
    }
```

I have been trying to work on the for loop function in R but I could not replicate the same command.

```
    for (x in 1:12) {
      NTM_base$Info_[x]i = ifelse(is.na(NTM_base$Info_[x]m), NA, NTM_base$Info_[x]i))
    }
```

This function did not work out.

I was hoping to do something as follows:

```
    NTM_base$Info_1i= ifelse(is.na(NTM_base$Info_1m), NA, NTM_base$Info_1i) 
    NTM_base$Info_1m= ifelse(is.na(NTM_base$Info_1i), NA, NTM_base$Info_1m) 
    NTM_base$Info_2i= ifelse(is.na(NTM_base$Info_2m), NA, NTM_base$Info_2i) 
    NTM_base$Info_2m= ifelse(is.na(NTM_base$Info_2i), NA, NTM_base$Info_2m) 
    NTM_base$Info_3i= ifelse(is.na(NTM_base$Info_2m), NA, NTM_base$Info_3i) 
    NTM_base$Info_3m= ifelse(is.na(NTM_base$Info_3i), NA, NTM_base$Info_3m) 
    NTM_base$Info_4i= ifelse(is.na(NTM_base$Info_4m), NA, NTM_base$Info_4i)... *code continues*
```

Edit: Thanks for the individual that help edit the dataset!

Comment: Could you elaborate? sorry i am still very new to R

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible example of your dataframe (you can use `dput(head(df))` along with your expected output so we are able to help you further

Comment: In R you would use a single list with multiple items for this instead of multiple variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a for loop you can select the columns with the same number and force NA in each row where at least one NA is present.

```r
# original data
df <- data.frame(Info_1i=c(1, 3, 3, 4, 5),
                 Info_1m=c(7, 3, NA, 4, 5),
                 Info_2i=c(3, 3, 6, 6, 8),
                 Info_2m=c(1, 1, 2, NA, 9),
                 Info_3i=c(1, 4, 5, 5, 5),
                 Info_3m=c(NA, 4, 5, 5, 5))

# get questions number (useful to retrieve the right columns)
id <- gsub("\\D", "", names(df))

# get unique id (to loop over)
uid <- unique(id)

for(i in uid){
  
  # get questions with the name id
  x <- df[, id == i]

  # if there is at least one NA in the row: force an NA in that position in every column
  x[apply(is.na(x), 1, any),] <- NA

  # reassign the now modified columns back to your dataframe
  df[, id == i] <- x

}

# final output
df
#>   Info_1i Info_1m Info_2i Info_2m Info_3i Info_3m
#> 1       1       7       3       1      NA      NA
#> 2       3       3       3       1       4       4
#> 3      NA      NA       6       2       5       5
#> 4       4       4      NA      NA       5       5
#> 5       5       5       8       9       5       5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! learnt a few new commands too!